# postgres dblink behavior difference between 9.2.3 and 9.2.4

Tags: postgresql-9.2

I am observing a difference in behavior of dblink between 9.2.3 and 9.2.4. I have two servers with identical postgres.conf and pg_hba.conf. However one on version 9.2.3 and one on 9.2.4

## 9.2.3

pg_hba.conf has

```
    local   all     dblinkuser      trust
```

then I connect to database using any ordinary user

```
    theater_map=# select dblink_connect('dbname=TheaterDB user=dblinkuser password=dbl123');
    dblink_connect 
    ----------------
    OK
    (1 row)
```

### success in connection.

## 9.2.4

my pg_hba.conf has the same entry as above

```
    theater_map=> select dblink_connect('dbname=TheaterDB user=dblinkuser password=dbl123');
    ERROR:  password is required
    DETAIL:  Non-superuser cannot connect if the server does not request a password.
    HINT:  Target server's authentication method must be changed.
```

NOW 
I change my pg_hba.conf on 9.2.4 as below

```
    local   all     dblinkuser      md5
```

and restart postgres

```
    theater_map=> select dblink_connect('dbname=TheaterDB user=dblinkuser password=dbl123');
    dblink_connect 
    ----------------
   OK
   (1 row)
```

---

I Checked the change log between versions 9.2.3 and 9.2.4 but could not find any details.

*note: changing auth method from trust to md5 on 9.2.3 does not make any difference and still works.*